# Programming with opencv, dll, visual studio and labview

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, labview

I am trying to build a module with two functions using opencv c++ in visual studio. I need to create a dll out of the program and use the dll in labview for processing a segment. Can anyone provide with an example code on how to create a dll using c++ program.

Answer (score 0):

Using

> extern "C" {

```
_declspec (dllexport) void function_name(parameters)
```

}
This helps anyone to create a dll and import in labview.